# Can we expose Experience Optimization results via Public Content API for the applications not built on DXA?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, sites-9, experience-optimization

We are using SDL 9 along with DXA 2.0 to host our website. We now want to expose the content to other platforms which are built on different technologies.
XO gives us the possibility to display promotions based on the different triggers which can be displayed on a specific page region of the DXA website.
But, if other platforms want to use component presentation or just the content based on some personalization rules or content tagging, can we expose the same via PCA or via any other solution?